# How to stop monthly cron output email

Tags: cron, email

Server is Debian 6.0. In /etc/aliases I have;

```
root: me@mydomain.com
```

This is so that root emails get sent directly to me. Today, a monthly script I have placed into /etc/cron.monthly has emailed me it's output. It a fairly simply script which looks like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /a/directory
rm -rf ./*
wget http://www.site.com/fresh-copy.zip
unzip fresh-copy.zip
rm fresh-copy.zip
```

The email I have received is below;

```
**Subject**: Cron <root@myserver> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
**From**: root@my.server.com
**Body**:

    /etc/cron.monthly/speedtest:
--2013-03-01 06:52:01--  http://www.site.com/fresh-copy.zip
Resolving www.site.com... 11.22.33.44
Connecting to www.site.com|11.22.33.44|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 99763924 (95M) [application/zip]
Saving to: `fresh-copy.zip'

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.7M 8s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.3M 8s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.4M 8s
        *CUT OUT FOR BREVITY*
 97350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 16.9M 0s
 97400K .......... .......... .....                           100% 11.6M=9.7s

2013-03-01 06:52:11 (9.78 MB/s) - `fresh-copy.zip' saved [99763924/99763924]

Archive:  fresh-copy.zip
  inflating: file1.ext
  inflating: file2.ext
  inflating: file3.ext
  inflating: file4.ext
  inflating: file5.ext
```

The only output in this email is from the `wget` and `unzip` command. I can edit the script and place `> /dev/null` on the end on those two lines, but is that really the best way to do this? If I add more commands to the script that produce output, I will always have to add on `> /dev/null` to each line. Is there a way I can disable email notification of output from this cron script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier method is to instead of adding the script to the cron.monthly directory, you add it to an old-fashioned crontab, where you can specify on the crontab line that you want output to go to /dev/null. Like this:

```
crontab -e
```

to edit the crontab. Then add the following line:

```
@monthly /path/to/script > /dev/null
```

This will mean that STDOUT gets redirected to /dev/null, but STDERR will still end up in an email. If you don't want to get mails on error either, the line should look like this:

```
@monthly /path/to/script > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend that you keep using `> /dev/null` in your script (or use the `-q` option for `wget` and `unzip`).  This way, if one of the commands throws errors, these will still be emailed to you, but normal output will be suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [`cronic`](http://habilis.net/cronic/) for a while, it has never failed me.

Essentially it's a wrapper script for your cron, which will only send you email if there is an error return code, or if there is something in stderr. This way you don't get spammed every time the cron runs, but still get notified when something is wrong.

To use it, download the cronic script and change your cron command from (for example)

```
* * * * * awesome_command
```

to

```
* * * * * /path/to/cronic awesome_command
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "mute" only this script you can put `/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the line calling your file in the crontab file. With this method you can't put your script in the monthly folder, you need to edit the crontab file with :

```
contab -e
```

Or you can edit cron config and remove your mail from it. Every thing is explained [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-the-mail-alert-by-crontab-command/).